R sf doesn't read WFS data properly
I tried to read data from France IGN services using WFS protocol and sf::st_read()
I'm using this url :
https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&BBOX=47.198,-1.575,47.213,-1.522&outputFormat=application/json
I can open the url, get the JSON file and open it with QGIS, it works just fine:

But R seems to have an issue with it and I don't understand why.
Maybe someone here can provide some insight.
It looks like this in WGS84 
And like this in IGNF:RGF93CC47  my other data use.

I opened the data in QGIS and the position is wrong (data placed off the coast of Somalia) and the orientation is wrong (North-South instead of East-West)

Here is the code I used:
wfs_url <- "WFS:https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&BBOX=47.198,-1.575,47.213,-1.522&outputFormat=application/json"

# Raw data (WGS84)
data_wgs84 <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url) |>
    tibble::rowid_to_column() |> dplyr::select(rowid)# keep only ID

sf::st_crs(data_wgs84)['input']

bbox <- sf::st_bbox(data_wgs84)

ggplot(data = data_wgs84) +
    geom_sf() +
  geom_rect(xmin = bbox['xmin'], xmax = bbox['xmax'], ymin = bbox['ymin'], ymax = bbox['ymax'], 
     fill = NA, colour = "black", linewidth = 1.5) 

# RGF93CC47 (aka EPSG:3947m not working either)

data_3947 <- data_wgs84 |> sf::st_transform(sf::st_crs("IGNF:RGF93CC47"))
sf::st_crs(data_3947)['input']

bbox <- sf::st_bbox(data_3947)

ggplot(data = data_3947) +
    geom_sf() +
  geom_rect(xmin = bbox['xmin'], xmax = bbox['xmax'], ymin = bbox['ymin'], ymax = bbox['ymax'], 
     fill = NA, colour = "black", linewidth = 1.5) 

# sf::st_write(data_wgs84, dsn = 'output_data.gpkg', layer = 'data_wgs84',append=FALSE)
# sf::st_write(data_3947, dsn = 'output_data.gpkg', layer = 'data_3947',append=FALSE)

Complete test notebook available here: https://github.com/nicolas-roelandt/test-sf-wfs

its flipped the lat-long coordinates on read. You've got data for the area you want, only its been X-Y flipped, probably by GDAL or R, when st_read is called. There's possibly a WFS parameter to fix this, or you have take the data apart (with st_coordinates) and put it back together again. Or there's an easier way... Just a comment for now, might work up a full answer later but maybe someone else will..

In the interest of "minimal examples" its clear the first thing to go wrong is st_read, if you consider the bounding box that st_read prints for you. There's no need to add anything after that one function to your question or construct that test notebook. If I see a lot of R code in a Q I think "oh no I have to get all those lines working to replicate the error" and that puts me off answering.

It is getting data for the correct bounding box but at some point the X-Y coordinates are being transposed. This is not uncommon with lat-long systems.
To fix, specify the coordinate system in an SRSName= parameter in your WFS URL:
wfs_url = "WFS:https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&BBOX=47.198,-1.575,47.213,-1.522&outputFormat=application/json&SRSName=epsg:4326"

Then its in the right position for further transforms if you need it. The bbox of the data here is around -1 longitude +47 lat and not vice-versa which was putting you in the Indian Ocean.
> data_wgs84 <- st_read(dsn = wfs_url) 
Reading layer `BDTOPO_V3:batiment' from data source 
  `WFS:https://data.geopf.fr/wfs/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=BDTOPO_V3:batiment&BBOX=47.198,-1.575,47.213,-1.522&outputFormat=application/json&SRSName=epsg:4326' 
  using driver `WFS'
Simple feature collection with 4176 features and 29 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: -1.575629 ymin: 47.19709 xmax: -1.521739 ymax: 47.21347
z_range:       zmin: -1000 zmax: 63.1
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

And mapview::mapview(st_zm(data_wgs84)) looks good.


Thanks @Spacedman, that fixes the issue. Simple but I didn't thought about it.

Can you tick the tickmark to accept this as the answer? That helps the system know it has a solution to this problem.

Already did it ^^'
